# Multiplo Schema com base no subdomain Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5

Estou criando uma aplicação que, quando o cliente estiver criando a estrutura da sua loja, ele ganhará um subdomínio (que ele mesmo irá escolher) e o banco de dados que o Laravel irá buscar terá o nome do subdomínio. EX:

1. cliente fecha o contrato;
2. dentro de um wizzard, ele seleciona que seu subdomínio será **foo**;
3. em seguida irei criar o banco com o mesmo subdomínio **foo**.myapp.com;
4. a partir disso, o Laravel deve buscar tal banco para tal domínio

Existe alguma forma de que eu possa definir o banco de acesso com base no subdomínio?

Comment: fiz bem resumido amigão. já tá tarde! ;)

Comment: Olá, dê uma olhada neste link (inglês), se entendi bem o seu problema isso irá te ajudar a criar esse dinamismo sem ter que ficar criando um modelo sempre que um cliente surgir. https://lukevers.com/2015/03/25/on-the-fly-database-connections-with-laravel-5/

Answer (score 1):

No laravel, no arquivo  `config/database.php` você pode definir mais de uma conexão com bancos

Exemplo:

```
  'default' => 'mysql_1',
  'mysql_1' => [
      ...
  ],
  'mysql_2' => [
     ...
  ]
```

Nas rotas você fará algo como:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'), function()
{
    // Wallace é o $account
    Route::get('user/{id}', function($account, $id)
    {
        App\Wallace\TabelaModel::find($id);
    });

});
```

Aí você poderia ter o namespace do cliente. Nos models desse cliente você poderia definir a conexão assim:

```
class TabelaModel extends Model
{
     protected $connection = 'mysql_2';
}
```

Comment: mas assim eu sempre teria que definir um model específico para este cliente. a minha lógica seria ter **"n"** bancos de dados para a mesma aplicação, mas para cada subdomain => 1 banco

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema, você conseguiu resolver?